# Array overflow while calculating sum of digits of a number

Tags: java

I can't seem to find how is the array overflowing. Everything seems to be fine.

```
class sumofnum  {

static int calculate_sum(String num)    {

    int len, sum = 0, i;

    len = num.length();

    int[] arr = new int[len - 1];

    // fill in array.
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        arr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));

    // calculate sum.
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        sum += arr[i];

    return sum;

} // method calculate_sum ends.
```

I used the above method to try to calculate sum of digits.

Actual output :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at sumofnum.calculate_sum(sumofnum.java:18)
    at sumofnum.main(sumofnum.java:40)
```

Comment: What are you passing as `num`?

Comment: This is a program for calculating sum of digits of a number. The variable num contains the number in String form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1):

Substitute `int[] arr = new int[len - 1];` for `int[] arr = new int[`**`len`**`];`.

You need to create the array where you're going to store the string characters the **same length as the string** (numbers of characters).

Otherwise you will get the mentioned exception in this line in the last iteration:

```
arr[i] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```java
int[] arr = new int[len - 1];
```

While the index goes from 0 to `len-1`, the size is `len`. Use instead:

```java
int[] arr = new int[len];
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is at

```
int[] arr = new int[len - 1];
```

the array created is of size less then the length of the string, thats why at last iteration it gives index out of bound exception

Also you can use a single loop to do both adding and getting the integer of character avoiding array itself by doing

```
   for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
    sum+= Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i));
}
```

Comment: This is what I used later. Thanks all of you. Great community, never expected such a swift response.